# How to solve floor(x/2) · ceil (2/x) = 17?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So i need to solve for x in the equation floor(x/2) * ceil(2/x) = 17.

If we assume x is an integer, then x/2 * 2/x = 17 implies that x has no integral value.

If x is not an integer, then let x = k + m where k is an integer but m belongs to (0, 1).

Now I have,
floor(k+m/2) * ceil(2/k+m) = 17.

Does it make any sense? Can we solve this equation in this way?

Comment: $17=17\cdot 1$ can be used. Why is $x=34$ not integral?

Comment: $x$ being an integer would not make $\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor \cdot \lceil \frac{2}{x}\rceil = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{x}$... It doesn't matter whether $x$ is an integer or not for such a simplification... what matters is if the *input of the floor function* is an integer or not and whether the *input of the ceiling function* is an integer or not.  $x$ may be the input of $f(x)$... but do not make the mistake of saying that $x$ is the input of $f(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: To emphasize, $\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor$ is not the same thing as $\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{2}$.  Consider what happens for $x>2$... what would $\frac{2}{x}$ look like?  It is two divided by a number bigger than two...  What would $\lceil \frac{2}{x}\rceil$ look like then?  Does that help to simplify things enough that you can solve from there?  Now, consider the opposite, what happens if $0\leq x<2$, what would $\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\rfloor$ look like here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments already, you seem to have confused $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor$ with $\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{2}$.  These are not the same.

We have the product of two integers equaling $17$.  As $17$ is prime this can only happen in one of four ways: $17\cdot 1,~1\cdot 17,~(-17)\cdot (-1),$ and $(-1)\cdot (-17)$

So, the question becomes "*When can $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor = 17$ and does $\left\lceil \dfrac{2}{x}\right\rceil = 1$ in any of those instances?*"

One should quickly see (*by looking at a graph or otherwise*) that $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor = 17$ happens whenever $x\in[34,36)$ and every $x$ in that range has $\left\lceil\dfrac{2}{x}\right\rceil = 1$ so these are all solutions.

Move to the next case: "*When can $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor = 1$ and does $\left\lceil \dfrac{2}{x}\right\rceil = 17$ in any of those instances?*"

Well, $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor = 1$ when $x\in[2,4)$ but in this range we still have $\left\lceil \dfrac{2}{x}\right\rceil = 1$ so no solutions exist of this second form.

Complete the problem by investigating the cases of $(-17)\cdot (-1)$ and $(-1)\cdot (-17)$.